# writeFileSync Returning Invalid Argument Type error in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a script to automatically make a new directory with 3 files inside. The "mkdirSync" part works but the "writeFileSync" is returning an error that my argument is not a string.

```
const fs = require('fs')

const folderName = process.argv[2] || 'Project'

try {
    fs.mkdirSync(folderName);
    fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/index.html`);
    fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/styles.css`);
    fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/script.js`);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Error:")
    console.log(e)
}
```

This is the error I am getting in the terminal for reference
[image]

Comment: You are telling `writeFileSync` where to write the file to but not WHAT to write into the file. It takes at least two arguments via [`writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)

Comment: You forgot to specify what to write into the file. You are not passing the second argument (`data`) with the contents of the file and hence you get an error telling you that (it is `undefined` because it is missing altogether).

Comment: What am I supposed to pass in as the (data) arguement?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to create a file without writing anything to it immediately, consider using `fs.openSync` (instead of fs.writeFileSync) with either 'a' or 'w' flag passed. You can even close this file descriptor right after creating it, like this:

```
fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(`${folderName}/index.html`, 'a')); // etc
```

The difference between 'a' and 'w' is subtle: both create a file if it doesn't exist. Yet if it does, it will be truncated with 'w' (the same behavior as you have with `writeFile`) - and left untouched with 'a' (the same as `appendFile`).

Answer (score 0):

Since I didnt want the files to come with anything written in them, passing in an empty string as the second argument fixed the error.

```
    const fs = require('fs')

const folderName = process.argv[2] || 'Project'

try {
    fs.mkdirSync(folderName);
    fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/index.html`, "");
    fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/styles.css`, "");
    fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/script.js`,"");
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Error:")
    console.log(e)
}
```